# Postgres Not working with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Postgres - 9.3
Ruby - 1.9.3
OS X - 10.8.5

```
Matthews-MacBook-Pro-2:truelink Matthew$ rake db:create:all
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:284: warning:    
Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/rvm in PATH, mode 040777
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have reviewed all existing questions posted on this issue and have not been able to resolve it reviewing the answers.

Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here?

**EDIT**

PostgresSQL is running via the Postgres.App I downloaded via http://postgresapp.com/

When I run

```
$ sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

I get

```
/private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

My .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7` export    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin
```

When I run

```
$ which postgres
```

I get

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/postgres
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a PostgreSQL server running?

Comment: Yes I do have PostgresSQL serve running on Port 5432.

Comment: Are you sure it is running?

Comment: Well, hmmm, maybe not...can you provide some guidance?  I'm using the application from http://postgresapp.com/.

Comment: Is postresapp running? Shouldn't there be an icon in the dock or something if it is? I don't use it so I'm guessing.

Comment: Yeah! It is running! I just got nervous that I was missing something else...but for sure it is running, the icon and it states it is running on Port 5432.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like something (most likely pg) is loading libxml before nokogiri loads.

try moving nokogiri to the top of your gemfile and bundling again.

if not, as suggested [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/742) you can use the libxml version that's shipped with pg (it should not have an adverse effect on nokogiri).

Comment: Thanks Mary Elizabeth! I ended up resolving the issue by unlinking some formulae noted by Brew Doctor.